# correct query to get a certain number of ancestors from one node

Tags: neo4j

I need to get a certain number of ancestors from my dataset from a certain node.

I can acheive this using that query:

```
MATCH (n:Dog {tag:5675220})-->(a)-->(b)-->(c)-->(d)-->(e)
RETURN n, a, b, c, d, e
```

is there a more efficient way of doing it? I do generate the query for the time being but not very classy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this more classy? :)

```
MATCH path = (n:Dog {tag:5675220})-[*5]->()
RETURN nodes(path)
```

Comment: it is indeed a blast!